# Random Forests, prediction are switched / flipped

Tags: classification, random-forest, prediction, accuracy

Quick question: I've been always told that if a binary classifier shows a very low accuracy (~0) you can switch the predictions to get an high accuracy (~1).

It actually never happened to me before, but now I have a Random Forests classifier which gives a prediction ~0. If I invert the predictions, then I get an accuracy ~1.

I'm trying to figure it out why at a certain point it decides to classify the data in class 1 as class 0, and vice versa.

Any idea what I should look for?

The classifier is the standard TreeBagger of MATLAB.

Comment: Do you use stratification or weighting? Is the training set and test set balanced?  Do you speak of out-of-bag accuracy or external test set accuracy?

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling The training and the test sets have been artificially balanced, meaning that I doubled the samples in class 0 to get 50-50. External test set accuracy. I don't know what is the difference between stratification and weighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling samples creates doublets, which easily becomes miss leading for a CV. Also it can potentially disturb the robustness of your ensemble.  I don't use treeBagger. But I read you can set prior='Uniform'. Try that instead of doublets.

For a better performance evaluation make Treebagger output OOB-class probabilities and evaluate these against true class labels in a ROC-plot. This matlab guide should help you: http://www.mathworks.com/examples/statistics/2205-classifying-radar-returns-for-ionosphere-data-using-treebagger

Comment: yes yes, the accuracy of ~0 (or ~1 if you reverse it) is given by the ROC curve. But I try with the prior instead of doubling the 0-class data.